# a simple situation about javascript split

Tags: javascript

What I need is simple but I just cant figure ou the logic to do it, I have the following string:

```
"data1":"content1",
"data2":"content2.1,"0",
"data3":"contente3",
```

I'm using the `.split(",")` to turn them in an array and then I remove the " so I can get something like:

```
array[0] = data1; array[1] = content1;
```

the problem is when I reach data2, are there any way to do the following?

```
array[0] = data2; array[1] = content2.1,"0"
```

Comment: "content2.1,"0", isn't even valid. it should be "content2.1","0"

Comment: Is this a question about escaping characters?

Comment: If the big string in the beginning has the newlines in it, try splitting on `",\n"` that way it won't capture the comma between content2.1 and "0"

Comment: @John: If it is an arbitrary text format, then there is nothing you can validate it against. It does not make sense to talk about "valid" or "invalid" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    var string = '"data1":"content1", "data2":"content2.1,"0", "data3":"contente3"';
    string.replace(':', ',');
    var strings = string.trim(',');
```